# On click of a checkbox, how to set all previous checkbox as checked in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have few check boxes having label as (Beginner,Intermediate, Advanced, Expert etc..)

Now I want on click of any checkbox , all previous checkbox should checked.

Ex : If I click on Advanced, only all previous check boxes should get checked except the expert.

Below is the code to get the list of check boxes. Please let me know if any solution is there.

```
<div class="cb-cont" *ngFor = "let circle of [1,2,3,4], let i = index;"   >
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" [attr.id]="'vacancy' + i" (change)="changeCheckbox(i)" [checked]=" (i==0) ? true : false"  >
        <label [attr.for]="'vacancy' + i" ><i class="xico-completed"></i></label>
</div>


changeCheckbox(i) {
    var elem = <HTMLInputElement>event.target
    elem.checked = true;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Gobli's Answer

**component**

```
selectedCheckbox = 0;
k = 0;

public changeCheckbox(i) {
 debugger;
 this.selectedCheckbox = i;
 var elem = <HTMLInputElement>event.target;
 if(elem.checked){
   this.k=1;
   elem.checked = true;  
 }else{
   this.k=0;
   elem.checked = false; 
 }
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="cb-cont" *ngFor = "let circle of [1,2,3,4], let i = index;"   >
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" [attr.id]="'vacancy' + i" 
 (change)="changeCheckbox(i)" [checked]="(k==1) ?( (i<=selectedCheckbox) ? true : false ) :( (i>=selectedCheckbox) ? false : true ) "  >
    <label [attr.for]="'vacancy' + i" ><i class="xico-completed"></i>
```

hope this helps u.
https://angular-2hh27h.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can store the index of the selected checkbox and select all the previous ones. Like this:

```
<div class="cb-cont" *ngFor = "let circle of [1,2,3,4], let i = index;"   >
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb" [attr.id]="'vacancy' + i" (change)="changeCheckbox(i)" [checked]=" (i<=selectedCheckbox) ? true : false"  >
        <label [attr.for]="'vacancy' + i" ><i class="xico-completed"></i></label>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
  selectedCheckbox = 0;
  public changeCheckbox(i) {
    this.selectedCheckbox = i;
    var elem = <HTMLInputElement>event.target;
    elem.checked = true;  
  }
```

Here you have a working stackblitz with the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29qko

Comment: Thanks @Gobli , Its working for me till  the now, Can we extend this function by adding a uncheck function also. Ex: (1) If I clicked the 5th checkbox by mistake and I want to uncheck it , what we can do here.(2) If all checkboxes are selected and I want to uncheck all check box along with 2nd check box on click on of it.

Comment: No problem @SiluK. I don't quite understand the uncheck function, can you explain it a little further? I thought that it was obligatory to at least select one, so if you by mistake select the 4th checkbox, you can select any inferior checkbox to deselect that.

PS: If the answer solved your question, can you mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for response @Gobli, Anyways I got the solution as your answer  is updated by Jomy Joseph

Answer (score 0):

**COMPONENT**

```
private checked: number = 0;

changeCheckbox(index, e) {
    if (index === 0) {
        e.target.checked = true;
        this.checked = 0;
        return;
    }

    if (e.target.checked) {
        if ((this.checked+1) === index) {
            this.checked = index;
        }else {
            e.target.checked = false;
        }
    } else {
        e.target.checked = true;
        this.checked = index;
    }
}

getChecked(i) {
    return (i <= this.checked);
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="cb-cont" *ngFor = "let circle of [1,2,3,4], let i = index;"   >
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" [attr.id]="'vacancy' + i" (change)="changeCheckbox(i, $event)" [checked]="getChecked(i)"  >
            <label [attr.for]="'vacancy' + i" ><i class="xico-completed"></i></label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Antonio de la mata , this is also working , but when we click the check boxes randomly to check and uncheck , something wrong is happening.

Comment: If you need more help I can

Comment: Yes please, @Antonio de la mata, Below is the scenario which I want to cover , Its working for me till the now, Can we extend this function by adding a uncheck function also. Ex: (1) If I clicked the 5th checkbox by mistake and I want to uncheck it , what we can do here.(2) If all checkboxes are selected and I want to uncheck all check box along with 2nd check box on click on of it

Comment: I have update the example, try it and say me If work as you want!

Comment: Help you the changes?